# Converting from Matrix4 to Vec3,Quaternion,Vec3 and back again

Tags: matrix, libgdx, quaternions

Libgdx uses a Matrix4 to express the world space position, rotation and scaleing of objects.

As I am animating these objects a lot in my code I wish to convert them to a format that keeps Position, Rotation and Scale Separate.
This makes it easier to interpolate correctly in order to animate them.

I am storing the Scale and Position both as Vector3s.
And the rotation as a Quaternion.

Here is my class that stores these 3 and converts two and from a Matrix4;

```js
public class PosRotScale {

 private static String logstag="ME.PosRotScale";
 
 Vector3 position = new Vector3();
 Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion();  
 Vector3 scale = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);
 
 public PosRotScale(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale) {
  super();
  
  this.position = position;
  this.rotation = rotation;
  this.scale = scale;
  
 }

    public PosRotScale(Matrix4 setToThis) {
  
  this.setToMatrix(setToThis);  
  
 }

 @Override
 public String toString(){
  
  Vector3 axis = new Vector3();
  float angle = rotation.getAxisAngle(axis);
  
  
  String stateAsString = "["+position.x+","+position.y+","+position.z+"]"
                 + "["+axis.x+","+axis.y+","+axis.z+","+angle+"]"
                 + "["+scale.x+","+scale.y+","+scale.z+"]";
  
  return stateAsString;
  
  
 }

 
 public void setToMatrix(Matrix4 lastLocation) {
  
  lastLocation.getTranslation(position); 
  lastLocation.getRotation(rotation);
  lastLocation.getScale(scale); 
  
 }


    public PosRotScale setToRotation(float i, float j, float k, float angleInDeg) {
  rotation.set(new Vector3(i,j,k), angleInDeg);      
  
  return this;
 }

 
 public PosRotScale setToPosition(Vector3 newposition) {
  position = newposition.cpy();

  return this;
 }

 
 public PosRotScale setToScaling(Vector3 newscale) {
  scale = newscale.cpy();
  
  return this;
 }

 public Matrix4 createMatrix() {
  return  new Matrix4(position,rotation.nor(),scale);
 }
 
 
 
}
```

(I apologise for the snippet above having a "run as" and being interpreted as javascript - I didn't see a option in the code snippet box for Java)

Anyway, in order to test if this was working I created a test state and converted to and from it.
Unfortunately the values clearly didn't match.
I expected the rotation to be off a bit (seems to be the nature of rotations) but scale is clearly wayyyy of. Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong?

Test code;

```
    PosRotScale startScaleAndRotation = new PosRotScale();
    startScaleAndRotation.setToPosition(new Vector3(30f, 40f, 50f));
    startScaleAndRotation.setToRotation(0f, 0f, 1f, 45);
    startScaleAndRotation.setToScaling(new Vector3(0.5f, 2.5f,0.5f));
    Gdx.app.log(logstag, " setting to: "+startScaleAndRotation.toString()); 
    Matrix4 test = startScaleAndRotation.createMatrix();
    PosRotScale test2 = new PosRotScale(test);
    Gdx.app.log(logstag, " check after conversion: "+test2.toString());
```

Results in:

```
setting to: [30.0,40.0,50.0][0.0,0.0,0.99999994,45.000004][0.5,2.5,0.5]
check after conversion: [30.0,40.0,50.0][0.0,0.0,1.811493,35.83953][1.8027757,1.8027754,0.5]
```

Comment: Have a look at http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17878&p=75338#p75338

Comment: Is the implication of your method that you simply cant convert from Matrix to Pos/Rot/Scale, only visa versa is possible?
I think your "set(position, rotation, scale);" is doing the same as when I "createMatrix" and replace the transformation with the new one. But you never convert a matrix - you simply use your alternative object from the start.
Also I notice you didn't normalise the rotation. I only put that in as Matrix4s description seemed to ask for it. 

Its certainly possible for me to convert to your method,although it makes my movement controller a bit less "universal".

Comment: Ok, going to adapt your method anyway (was worried about linking it to the camera as my current animation system does that fine, but I can always still convert to PosRotScale using my current [half working] method for the camera and use pure PosRotScale for the rest). Assuming it works if you make a post as an answer I'll accept it.